# Scroll window to top of Iframe from iFrame with different domain than parent

Tags: javascript, iframe

**Context**:

1. PARENT PAGE loads an IFRAME that contains an app/plugin
2. PARENT PAGE has *different domain* than the IFRAME
3. PARENT PAGE and IFRAME both have installed the `iframeResizer` plugin -> the iframe has **no scroll bar** (all content is shown on parent page) - IFRAME is always resized based on its document height
4. PARENT PAGE html/js *cannot be changed*, only the IFRAME

**Problem**:

If the user is at the bottom of the IFRAME, and performs an action, how do you scroll him at the TOP OF THE IFRAME?

Solutions that **DO NOT** work:

1. `window.scrollTo(0,0); // from iframe`
2. anything with `window.parent` from iframe (cannot access)
3. use an anchor at top of iframe body and rewrite `window.location`

**Solutions that do work?**

1. will post one as an answer (it works, but it's weird...and not good for IE)

[image: scroll problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [document.body.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

It should work on IE8+ and the other browsers (I only tested it in Chrome, FF and IE11)

See codepen [demo here](https://codepen.io/danmana/pen/LOLEgg).

```
document.body.scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the right approach. Did not know about scrollIntoView method. (I've looked for window methods, not element)

Answer (score 1):

This works fine in Chrome & Mozilla (IE not working, why?) ... but it doesn't seem like the right approach.

**DEMO** [Code pen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LOyydE)

1. Create an `input` field in the IFRAME
2. Style the INPUT to make it *not visible* to the user
3. Scroll parent page by **focusing** the `input` from the IFRAME

```
    // IFRAME JS
    // initialize a "scroller" object
    var scrollPage = (function(){
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.style.position="absolute";
        input.style.top="-50px";
        document.body.insertBefore(input, document.body.firstChild);
        return function(){
            input.focus();
        };
    })();
    // use the "scroller" when needed
    scrollPage();
```